# How to fix "vsquish CHILDRENDUMMY not found in list of covariates"

Tags: stata, margins

I am getting an error when I put in these two codes. I am using Stata 12.

I have recoded `CHILDREN` already as a dummy variable called `CHILDRENDUMMY` and the variable is located in the list of variables. I am trying to run two `margins` commands, but I am getting the error message

> vsquish CHILDRENDUMMY not found in list of covariates

*First Code*

```
margins, dydx (DISAGMT) at (CHILDRENDUMMY= (0 1)) vsquish
```

*Second Code*

```
margins, at dydx (DISAGMT= (0) CHILDRENDUMMY= (0 1)) vsquish
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?margins for current syntax.

You should see that you have confused  `margins` on what you think is a covariate. For example, `vsquish` is an option, not a covariate. How did that happen?

The second syntax is not what you want, as `at()` needs an argument. That's like saying "meet me at" without time or place.

You don't say what you want to do, but my guess is more like

```
margins, dydx(DISAGMT) at(CHILDRENDUMMY=(0 1)) vsquish
```

Note that option names and their arguments should not be separated by spaces: the form is `foobar(frog)` not `foobar (frog)`.